# How to clean a microwave?

Tags: cleaning, microwave

I usually clean my microwave with a surface kitchen spray and was wondering what other tips and tricks do people use to clean their microwaves. Is there anything that should be avoided to not contaminate the food or to not damage the microwave?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You can put a cup/bowl of water(you can also add some vinegar if you don't mind the smell) in there, heat it up to boiling, let the steam out. Then you should let it sit in the microwave without opening the door.
- Wait for a few minutes, open the microwave, and wipe off the inside. All that steam should have soften any stains or food pieces left in there.
- You may spray some natural cleaners or lemon/vinegar mixtures to wipe off the inside more.

Comment: vinegar smells will usually go away after a couple of hours (or a few uses of the microwave)

Answer (score 1):

I also use the steam method above first. However, if it is particularly greasy, as when someone exploded a cheese dish, then the second step is a light scrub with baking soda. Final wipe down with damp papertowel.

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting a damp rag in and microwaving for 10 seconds on high. Then use the rag to clean it. If there are any bits which were still hard to get out, you can repeat this, or nuke the rag for 15 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I would put a towel with baking soda on it and get it wet and put it in the microwave for 30 seconds and then let it sit for a few minutes. Then wipe it out real good.  Repeat as necessary.

Comment: What's the point of microwaving the wet baking soda? It won't evaporate.